Electrum too many transactions on a single address
I have an Electrum wallet, and I use it a lot, and when I send or receive bitcoin I only use one address, now the address has around 10695 transactions, and I cannot send the bitcoin inside it using Electrum, when I try to send it gives me the error message "bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent" and I cannot see the latest transactions because Electrum is stuck on synchronizing after getting 3582 transactions.
I tried changing the gap limit to 400 with no result
relevant info:

the address is created using bip32 (private key uses p2wpkh)
I am using the latest Electrum version

